# Basic vector confusion

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors

The context is that there is a charge $q$ moving with velocity $\vec{V}$ in magnetic field $\vec{B}$. The angle between $\vec{V}$ and $\vec{B}$ is given as $30^{\circ}$

The formula to calculate the radius helical path of the charge is $r= mV / QB$.

My question is, do I consider the perpendicular component of Velocity in the direction of magnetic field, or
the perpendicular component of magnetic field in direction of velocity. Why?
(The answer of each are different as given below)

[image: why are the answers different]

Comment: The formula which you have written is only valid when both $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$ are perpendicular. It is not a general formula rather a special case of the general formula for radius of helical path.

Comment: please see this https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/22-5-force-on-a-moving-charge-in-a-magnetic-field-examples-and-applications/ .v is the speed in this simple formula. not a vector

Comment: @NipunKulshreshtha My question is that force is applied only when it is perpendicular, that is why we separate them into components. But why is there a difference in result when I separate velocity into its components rather than magnetic field into its components?

Comment: @annav In my book they have taken v as a vector and taken its components(my 1st way of doing it in the picture). What is the reason why you think v is a scalar here? I would disagree because of the importance directional nature of velocity here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your doubt is based on shortcut but the correct formula for calculating  magnetic force is-:
[image]

So when we use this instead of taking component of either velocity or magnetic field , we always get the right result and also the same result also comes when we take component of velocity which is not the standard way of using this in problems. For now, I am not able to describe you that why by taking component of velocity get the desired result but not with magnetic field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first diagram you have drawn. The force is calculated from $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}=qvBsin\theta\hat{z}$. I have assumed that the direction into the paper to be z, the field along the x-axis, and the initial velocity in the x-y plane. This causes the perpendicular component of velocity to change direction. Now it executes helical motion, with the magnitude of velocity associated with circular motion (i.e., tangential velocity in circular motion) being $vsin\theta$. Use the equation for centripetal force: $\frac{mv^2sin^2\theta}{r}=qvBsin\theta \implies r=\frac{mvsin\theta}{qB}$.

This is the derivation of the result. It does not matter which of the above diagrams is used, or how the components are resolved. What matters is the component of velocity that is tangential to the circular motion.

Comment: $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{F}$ will always remain perpendicular to each other. If I am not wrong, if velocity and acceleration are forever at angle $π/2$ , the particle would do a circular motion with that velocity's magnitude only. So shouldn't the magnitude of centripetal force be $\frac{mv^{2}}{r}$

Comment: Velocity and acceleration are forever at right angles, but the particle here is not executing pure circular motion. In this case, we have helical motion. There is no pure circular motion because we have a parallel component of velocity to the field and the velocity perpendicular to the field is what is responsible for the circular motion: very simply speaking, the plane of the 'circle' in this case is perpendicular to the x-axis, and thus the tangential component of velocity in this 'circle' is just $vsin\theta$, which is used here.